# How to select the first character after blank space

Tags: r, regex, string

I'd like to select the first character after blank space. My MWE is given by

## Input

```
a <- c("United States", "South America")
a
```

## Output desired

```
"S" "A"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example from base-R:

```
gsub(".* (\\C).*", "\\1", a, perl = TRUE)
[1] "S" "A"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
inds = regexpr(" ", a) + 1
substring(a, inds, inds)
#[1] "S" "A"
```

Or using `str_extract` of `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string = a, pattern = "(?<=\\s).")
#[1] "S" "A"
```